# Drop table only if it exists, or ignore drop error

Tags: sql, db2, drop-table

I have a table `MYLOG` and would like to try drop it before creating it using the SQL script below.
If the table does not exist yet, the error below is throw.
How could I bypass this error if the table does not exist?

The schema gets set in an earlier script, which is not available in the SQL script:

```
set current schema MYSCHEMA
```

SQL script:

```
DROP TABLE MYLOG;
CREATE TABLE MYLOG (
  TIME_STARTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TIME_STARTED_USER_EMAIL    PRIMARY KEY (TIME_STARTED, USER_EMAIL))  ORGANIZE BY ROW;
COMMIT;
```

Error:

```
DROP TABLE MYLOG
SQLError: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
SQLGetDiagRec: SQLState     : S0002
          fNativeError : -204
          szErrorMsg   : [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/6000] SQL0204N  "MYSCHEMA.MYLOG" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

Comment: whenever sqlerror continue / exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ

There's more than one way to do it.

You can use compound-SQL in your script with a continue-handler for the SQLSTATE corresponding to the error you get if the table is not found, but this requires that you also use an alternative statement delimiter like shown below

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

set current schema myschema@

BEGIN
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704'
   BEGIN end;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MYLOG';
END @

CREATE TABLE MYLOG(... )@
```

You can also change the abort-on-first-error  logic (if you use +s when running your script via the command line). You can udate the Db2 CLP options on the fly inside your script via `update command options using s off` (to continue on error) or `update command options using s on` to abort on error.

Answer (score 0):

by using this query

```
select tabname from syscat.tables where 
tabschema='myschema' and tabname='MYLOG'
```

check that table in your schema

if exist then

```
drop table myschema.MYLOG
```

then create

Comment: `myschema` is unknown with the SQL script